# Where is the documentation for Gradle's AntBuilder?

Tags: ant, gradle, porting, antbuilder

I'm porting an Ant build.xml to Gradle.  I wanted to use Gradle's AntBuilder to do something like

task mytask << {
  ant {
    jar(..) { ... }
  }
}

I am having some trouble with the syntax and can't figure out where AntBuilder is documented.  The Gradle user guide just points to the API [1] which is pretty useless.  As it doesn't document any of ant-tasks supported by AntBuilder (e.g. jar, copy, etc.).

Googling I found another person asking the same question [2] but no one answered.

[1] http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/AntBuilder.html
[2] http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Where-s-the-documentation-for-Antbuilder-tt2857050.html#none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AntBuilder` is documented in the "Using Ant from Gradle" chapter of the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html). That said, here are some further pointers:

- Gradle's `AntBuilder` is (virtually) the same as Groovy's `AntBuilder`. The syntax is a mechanical translation of the Ant XML syntax. To get started, check out the samples in the full Gradle distribution.
- `AntBuilder` can be used with any Ant task. For information on a particular Ant task, check its documentation.
- Third-party Ant tasks (i.e. Ant tasks that don't ship with Ant) have to be defined beforehand exactly as in Ant. For details, see the user guide chapter.